# Condición IF no valida correctamente en JAVASCRIPT

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, phpmyadmin, dom

Hola amigos necesito su ayuda, estoy desarrollando un modulo donde el usuario agrega productos con determinados identificadores, todo va bien, pero cuando el identificado es igual a uno que ya esta dentro del div no me esta respetando la validación, se salta una posicion en el bucle y se agrega otro elemento con el mismo ID

https://jsfiddle.net/joserangel/zow0k1qc/8/

Dejo el codigo:
el HTML:

```
    <div class="modal-body">

      <div class="box-body">

        <!-- ENTRADA PARA EL NOMBRE -->

        <div class="form-group">

          <div class="input-group">

            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-product-hunt"></i></span> 
            <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg" name="idpro" id="idpro" placeholder="Ingresar ID de producto" required>

          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

          <div class="input-group">

            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i></span> 

            <input type="text"  class="form-control input-lg" name="nameProductoOutbase"  id="nameProductoOutbase" placeholder="Ingresar NAME unitario del producto" required>

          </div>

        </div>
        <!-- ENTRADA PARA EL DOCUMENTO ID -->

        <div class="form-group">

          <div class="input-group">

            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i></span> 

            <input type="number"  class="form-control input-lg" name="cantidadCompra"  id="cantidadCompra" placeholder="Ingresar cantidad unitario del producto" required>

          </div>

        </div>


        <div class="form-group">

          <div class="input-group">

            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i></span> 

            <input type="number"  class="form-control input-lg" name="precioPro"  id="precioPro" placeholder="NUEVO precio unitario del producto" required>

          </div>

        </div>




    </div>


    <hr>
```

Agregar producto

y el JS:

```
function AgregarProductoOut() {

                var productosLista = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("productosLista"));


            var idProducto =  $("#idpro").val();
            var descripcion =   $("#nameProductoOutbase").val();
            var precioDB =    $("#precioPro").val();
            var stockDB =     "20";
            var cantidad =    $("#cantidadCompra").val();
            var totalprecionormal = precioDB * cantidad;
                var listaProductos = [];


              if (productosLista == null) {
                  listaProductos.push({ "id" : idProducto, 
                                        "descripcion" : descripcion,
                                        "cantidad" : cantidad,
                                        "stock" : stockDB,
                                        "precio" : precioDB,
                                        "total" : totalprecionormal
                   })


                  $("#listaProductos").val(JSON.stringify(listaProductos)); 
                  localStorage.setItem('productosLista', JSON.stringify(listaProductos));

                  $(".nuevoProducto").append(

                        '<div class="row namePro" style="padding:5px 15px">'+

                    '<!-- Descripción del producto -->'+

                        '<div class="col-xs-7" style="padding-right:0px">'+

                          '<div class="input-group">'+



                            '<input type="text" class="form-control nuevaDescripcionProducto" idProducto="'+idProducto+'" name="agregarProducto" value="'+descripcion+'" readonly required>'+

                          '</div>'+

                        '</div>'+

                        '<!-- Cantidad del producto -->'+

                        '<div class="col-xs-2">'+

                           '<input type="text" class="form-control nuevaCantidadProducto" onkeypress="return valida(event)" name="nuevaCantidadProducto" value="'+cantidad+'" stock="'+stockDB+'" nuevoStock="'+Number(stockDB-1)+'" required>'+

                        '</div>' +

                        '<!-- Precio del producto -->'+

                        '<div class="col-xs-3 ingresoPrecio" style="padding-left:0px">'+

                          '<div class="input-group">'+

                            '<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="ion ion-social-usd"></i></span>'+

                            '<input type="text" class="form-control nuevoPrecioProducto" precioReal="'+precioDB+'" name="nuevoPrecioProducto" value="'+totalprecionormal+'" disabled required>'+
                            '<input type="hidden" class="form-control nuevoPrecio"  value="'+precioDB+'" onkeypress="return valida(event)" required>'+
                          '</div>'+

                        '</div>'+

                      '</div>');

              }else{



                  for(var i = 0; i < $(".nuevoProducto").children().length; i++){
                    var itemID = $(".nuevoProducto").children().children().children().children(".nuevaDescripcionProducto").eq(i).attr("idProducto");
                      console.log(itemID);

                  }

                    if (itemID === idProducto) {
                      alert("es igual");
                    }else{
                      $(".nuevoProducto").append(

                        '<div class="row namePro" style="padding:5px 15px">'+

                        '<!-- Descripción del producto -->'+

                            '<div class="col-xs-7" style="padding-right:0px">'+

                              '<div class="input-group">'+


                                '<input type="text" class="form-control nuevaDescripcionProducto" idProducto="'+idProducto+'" name="agregarProducto" value="'+descripcion+'" readonly required>'+

                              '</div>'+

                            '</div>'+

                            '<!-- Cantidad del producto -->'+

                            '<div class="col-xs-2">'+

                               '<input type="text" class="form-control nuevaCantidadProducto" onkeypress="return valida(event)" name="nuevaCantidadProducto" value="'+cantidad+'" stock="'+stockDB+'" nuevoStock="'+Number(stockDB-1)+'" required>'+

                            '</div>' +

                            '<!-- Precio del producto -->'+

                            '<div class="col-xs-3 ingresoPrecio" style="padding-left:0px">'+

                              '<div class="input-group">'+

                                '<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="ion ion-social-usd"></i></span>'+

                                '<input type="text" class="form-control nuevoPrecioProducto" precioReal="'+precioDB+'" name="nuevoPrecioProducto" value="'+totalprecionormal+'" disabled required>'+
                                '<input type="hidden" class="form-control nuevoPrecio"  value="'+precioDB+'" onkeypress="return valida(event)" required>'+
                              '</div>'+

                            '</div>'+

                      '</div>');

                    }










              }




        }
```

Comment: probaste imprimir en consola los valores de `itemID` e `idProducto` para ver que estas comparando?

Comment: ya imprimí lo que me dices amigo y primero se comparan números diferentes, y cuando le vuelvo a dar en agregar producto ya me funciona la validación que tengo, es como si el ciclo se saltara una posición.

Comment: ese código que pegaste es sólo una fracción del total, no hay cómo reproducir tu caso localmente. Se entiende que incluyes alguna versión de bootstrap, pero el html completo y el JS completo serían útiles, y mejor todavía si puedes pegar el conjunto completo como un snippet. En éste puedes simular el localstorage usando un array vacío o el valor NULL en duro

Comment: amigo lo acabo de subir, aqui esta el enlace  https://jsfiddle.net/joserangel/zow0k1qc/8/

Comment: también arriba anexe el enlace amigo @amenadiel

Comment: primero que quires que haga exactamente?

Comment: @Bryro Hola amigo, quiero que mediante el botón agregar producto se vaya agregando al div de "nuevoProducto", agregar todos los productos que quiera, pero que valide si ingreso un mismo ID que ya este dentro del DIV, si el ID coincide con alguno que no lo ingrese, y si no coincide que lo deje ingresar, en el código que puse arriba, si me hace lo que pido, PERO cuando ingreso un mismo ID al primer intento no me valida, y ya cuando le doy nuevamente ahora si me valida la condición, y es lo que no entiendo que esta pasando, no se si me di a entender, espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

agrega esto como utilidad o buena practica!

```
var ids=[];
function existe(a,f){
   for(let i =0; i <= a.length;i++){
      if(i == f){
      return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

esto validara cada id nuevo
y lo implementas asi:

```
if(!exist(ids,idProducto)){
  ids.push(idProducto);
  // codigo  $(".nuevoProducto").append(....

}else{alert("ya existe este id sorry");}
```

Comment: Amigo la función existe(); la adaptaría dentro de la función agregarProducto??

Comment: la funcion va afuera la implemenatacion va dentro de agregaproducto!

Comment: Muchísimas gracias amigo con eso quedo perfecto!! :D